# Subprogram, typing out two integers

Tags: ada

The task is simple, but I cannot solve it for some reason given the following conditions:

Create a subprogram of type procedure where the user can enter two integers from
the keyboard. The integers must be delivered to the main program.
The main program should then print these numbers.

For instance:

Type two integers: **83 122**

The two integers were: 83 122

This is my approach:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Hello is

    procedure Two_Integers (Integer_1, Integer_2 : out Integer) is
        Integer_1, Integer_2 : Integer;
    
    begin          
        Put("Type two integers: ");
        Get(Integer_1);
        Get(Integer_2);
      
    end Two_Integers;

begin     
    Put("The two integers were: ");
    Two_Integers(Integer_1, Integer_2);
    Skip_Line;

end Hello;
```

I'm getting the following error codes:

```
Integer_1 conflicts with declaration at line 6
Integer_2 conflicts with declaration at line 6
Integer_1 is undefined
Integer_2 is undefined
```

I was thinking that my subprogram has two locally declared integer variables and then it'll send OUT "integer". Then in my main program I call this subprogram and type the integers out as instructed.

How can I solve this problem? Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to define two integers in the main procedure to be the actual parameters for your procedure Two_Integers. Neither Integer_1 nor Integer_2 are defined within the scope of procedure Hello.

Comment: @leun, a quick SO etiquette note: you've asked a bunch of questions recently, and that's good! You've gotten some good answers. It would be good etiquette to accept any answers you feel have adequately answered your questions.

Comment: Try compiling with `-gnatl` - it prints out your program with the error messages in line.

Comment: The message from those errors is : learn where declarations make things visible, aka the scope rules.

Answer (score 3):

Three issues with your code.

- Your `Two_Integers` procedure defines two parameters, but then you define local variables for the procedure with the same names. Is `Get` acting on the parameter or the local variable? *You don't actually need these local variables at all.*
- You never define `Integer_1` or `Integer_2` variables for `Two_Integers` to take as arguments.
- You never print the integers you read in to ensure your program did what you thought.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Hello is

    procedure Two_Integers (Integer_1, Integer_2 : out Integer) is
    begin          
        Put("Type two integers: ");
        Get(Integer_1);
        Get(Integer_2);
      
    end Two_Integers;

    Integer_1, Integer_2 : Integer;

begin     
    Put("The two integers were: ");
    Two_Integers(Integer_1, Integer_2);
    Skip_Line;
    Put_Line("The two integers were: " & I1'Image & " " & I2'Image);

end Hello;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with Ada.Text_IO;           use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;   use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure Hello is

    procedure Two_Integers (Integer_1, Integer_2 : out Integer) is
      
        Integer_1, Integer_2 : Integer;
      
     begin  
      
        Put("Type two integers: ");
        Get(Integer_1);
        Get(Integer_2);
      
     end Two_Integers;

   I1 , I2 : Integer;
     
begin
     Two_Integers(I1, I2);
     Skip_Line;
     Put_Line("The two integers were: " & I1'Image & " " & I2'Image);
end Hello;
```

Note that you also need to output the values, which you forgot to do.
Readability is also greatly increased if your indentation is consistent.